# How can I Bold only part of a string in an Excel cell with Python?

Tags: python, excel, formatting, win32com

I'm using win32com to fill out an Excel spreadsheet with some analytic information. I have a cell that I want to be in this form:

This is the problem description:  **this is the command you run to fix it**

I can't seem to figure out how to get the text into the cell with Python with mixed formatting.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
excel.Visible=True
sel = excel.Selection
sel.Value = "this is the command you run to fix it"
sel.Font.Bold = True
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = 'This is the problem description' + sel.Value  #makes the whole cell bold
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "{} {}".format("this is the problem desc",sel) #makes the whole cell bold
```

The selection object has a Characters attribute, but I can't find any documentation on what it does.

Comment: I... didn't even know Excel was *capable* of mixed formatting like this...

Comment: sure is: http://imgur.com/uHkBnzb

Comment: Huh. Didn't used to be.

Comment: @DerekChadwell, which excel version are you using?

Comment: Part of the office 2010 suite:

Version 14.0.6123.5001 (32-bit)

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in Excel you would differentially format the characters.  The characters property has a start and length argument; and an absolute requirement is that the contents of the cell be Text; and not the result of a formula.  Something like Range("A1").Characters(2,5).Font.Bold = true would Bold characters 2-6 in cell A1.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Has been a feature at least since 2007, if not before.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Well then that shows you just how long it's been since I've used Excel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [@ron-rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489355/how-do-i-bold-only-part-of-a-string-in-an-excel-cell-with-python/26490194#comment41613355_26489355), the VBA code to pull this off looks like:

```
Range("A1").Characters(2,5).Font.Bold = true
```

And similarly, there is a Characters object attribute of the excel WorkSheet's Range

```
>>> ws.Range("A1").Characters
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.Characters 967192>
```

HOWEVER, the method you need to access a range with that object is GetCharacters(start, length) (index starts at 1 as per usual with the excel com methods)

```
ws.Range("A1").GetCharacters(2,4).Font.Bold = True
```

You can use this command to update the boldness of characters in a cell after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

Although you are looking for a win32com solution in the body of your question I'll point out for anyone who gets here via the title that this is also possible in Python with XlsxWriter.

[Example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_rich_strings.html):

[image]