# PyWin32 Excel Cell Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I need to access to the Characters object with PyWIn32 in a similar way as it is done in VBA:

```
Sub print_characters_cell()
    dim idx as Long
    For idx= 1 To activeSheet.cells("A1").Characters.Count
        debug.print(cell.Characters(idx, 1))
    Next idx
End Sub
```

However when I try to use the object in Python and try to access to the individual character in a similar way in VBA, I get the following messages:

If I try to individually access to a character as

```
cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)
cell.Characters(1)
```

It returns a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'Characters' object is not callable
```

If I try to loop in the object Characters it returns that the object does not support enumeration.

Example:

```
for char in cell.Characters:
    print(char)
```

I get another TypeError Exception:

```
TypeError: This object does not support enumeration
```

And finally, if I try to use indexing with the object, also I get another TypeError:

```
cell.Characters[1]
```

I get the TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'Characters' object does not support indexing
```

Edit: Adding some code that allows to test it as has been suggested.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('excel.application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
sh = wb.ActiveSheet
cl = sh.Cells(1,1)
cl.Value = 'Some characters to check'
dir(cl.Characters)
```

And I have to use the cl.Characters as I have mentioned above, but none has worked, or got errors.

```
#TypeError
for char in cl.Characters:
    print(char.Text)
#TypeError
cl.Characters(1,1)
#TypeError
cl.Characters[1]
```

So, how I can handle individually the characters with Python?

Comment: Have you tried finding out what attributes/methods the `cell.Characters` objects have? Either through documentation or `dir(cell.Characters)`.

Comment: Yes, I did. It has:
['CLSID', 'Delete', 'Insert', '_ApplyTypes_', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_oleobj_', '_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']

Comment: What does the `cell.Characters.dict` contain?

Comment: The dict contains:
{'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x00000000040F3570 with obj at 0x0000000003FAC568>}

Comment: @TMikinos What attributes does the `cell` object have? Does it have `value`?

Comment: Yes, it does have Value.
cell.Value
However, I need to access to the characters individually as I need to extract information from them like Font. And through Value I lose Font information.

Comment: Please post all the code involved, not just parts, as explained in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done. I have added a small working snippet of code to test

Comment: I have investigated more about this, and it may look like it is a bug in the library win32com, as this COM object in Python should be callable and have a method __call__ but it does not have it. And it may be the issue. I've tried Comtypes and apparently in Comtypes is callable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26490194/), you'll need to use `.GetCharacters` instead of `.Characters`

```
cell.GetCharacters(1,1).Text
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. I solved this issue using ComTypes instead of pywin32, but I prefer pywin32 to comtypes.