# Adding new text into excel cell with another format using python & xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Hello I've recently embarked on a project that allows me to input some data into a python programme using Tinker. This the programme interface.

[image]

With this input after clicking "Go" it'll open an excel spreadsheet and write the start and end time for that specific date. My question is how do I write a code to have a different colour of text for the NEW text without altering say what was in the cell originally using xlsxwriter? Here's an example.

This is the original text/format for say 5th May cell in my excelsheet.
[image]

And after clicking Go, I hope to achieve this:
[image]

The coding of opening excel, writing, finding the cell, and saving. I'm ok with that.
I hope this is a clear enough question and hopefully it's an answer I can use!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the GetCharacters function done on a Range, using win32com (pywincom) will do what you want.

```
ws.Range(cell/range as string).GetCharacters(start,end).Font.Color = [color ID]
```

After opening the workbook, I was able to do this to make characters 2-5 as Red:

```
ws.Range('A1').GetCharacters(2,5).Font.Color = -16776961
```

I got a lot of this from a previous question looking at bolding: [How Do I Bold only part of a string in an excel cell with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489355/how-do-i-bold-only-part-of-a-string-in-an-excel-cell-with-python/26490194#26490194)

To get the color (and there is probably a better way), I went into Excel and used the [macro recorded](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b), and just changed the font the red and saw what the macro recorded called that color. So you could get the number ID for the colors you want from that.